# HANA SQL Syntax error

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

I am trying to translate some code to HANA SQL Script, however I get the following error

> "Incorrect syntax near 'is': line 29 col 76".

The "IS NULL" seems to be an issue, however I am not sure where to place it as I am only a beginner in SQL.

```
WHERE IS NULL(T2."Manual", '') = 'Y' AND T0."EntryNumber" = :list_of_cols_val_tab_del;
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Katie.

Comment: Correct syntax is `WHERE X IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

This query will not raise error:

```
WHERE IFNULL(T2."Manual", '') = 'Y' AND T0."EntryNumber" = :list_of_cols_val_tab_del;
```

And you should use this instead, the `IFNULL` function is not necessary in your case:

```
WHERE T2."Manual" = 'Y' AND T0."EntryNumber" = :list_of_cols_val_tab_del;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to what's below and the SP successfully executed. Thanks.

```
WHERE (T2."Manual" = 'Y' or T2."Manual" is NULL) AND T0."EntryNumber" = :list_of_cols_val_tab_del;
```